# Excel 2007 onclick event to open in Google

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I would like to add an Onclick event to a columns with values so a click on a value will automatically open a browser and search the value on Google. Is that even possible?

This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
Sub CallWebPage()
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
        Address:="http://www.google.com", _
        NewWindow:=True, _
        AddHistory:=True
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
End Sub
```

So I got the macro to open the browser on Google and now I'm trying to tell the macro process to copy the cell value to Google and search for it.

Comment: Yes.  It's possible.  Why don't you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: I have very little experience with Visual Basic and I wanted to believe it's something very simple. I guess I was wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 2 does a search on the activecell

```
Sub CallWebPage()
searchtopic = Replace(ActiveCell, " ", "+")
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
        Address:="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q= " & searchtopic, _
        NewWindow:=True, _
        AddHistory:=True
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: Line 2 captures the active cell and changes spaces to "+" then line 3 adds the search topic to your hyperlink request

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked great :) I was about to give up on this idea until you've posted this solution.